# fs mksdirsync creating folder in localhost but doesn't work in server

Tags: server, localhost, fs, mkdir

I use `mksdirsync` in my code, it works fine on my localhost,

But when i try to use it on the server (evennode if it matters) it doesn't create the new dir i wanted.

```
fs.mkdirSync("./app/public/users/",{recursive: true},  function (err){if(err) console.log('error', err);});
```

This is the line i'm using.

I even tried to write `__dirname` and it didn't work.

Thanks for the helpers.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No, i dont get any errors

Comment: The way you use this function seems weird. The sync variant does not accept a callback: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options
Could you try it async and check if you get an error?

Comment: Change to fs.mkdir?

Comment: Yes, in any case it's better to perform async operations in node.

Answer (score 0):

dont use callback with mkdirsync and problem is your path on server try to give your complete path starting from /home